# Impossible to "share" deep links using #?

Tags: html, ajax, facebook, deep-linking, addthis

Im working on a webapp and i would like to have social buttons like facebook-like etc.

Ive tried to use the html code/api from facebook, addthis, shareaholic, sharethis and none of them respects my deep links!

my paths look like aaa.com/bbb.html#ccc|ddd but no matter what i do, everything after # gets ignored!

What can i do?
I cant use javascript for my share buttons, they have to be html-only.

G

Answer (score 1):

You should create short urls for these links when sharing.  Use bit.ly or tiny url and when sending the information to facebook etc make sure to use the shortened url instead.

Also you should look into url rewritting to help you fix this problem.